# Python requests - check if a particular header exists

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I am working with python `requests` module where I am getting  a url.

`response = requests.get(url)`

This url has a set of headers where one particular header is sometimes there and sometimes not. I want to get the value of this header if it is there. I am using

```
retry_after = response.headers['Retry-After']
```

However when the header is not there an exception is thrown. what I want is something like this

```
If this header exists ( if header is not None)
    retry_after = response.header['Retry_After']
```

How can this be achieved with python `requests`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'd check for the existence of header keys as you would with any standard python dictionary.

```
if 'Retry_After' in response.headers:
    ... # do something
```

Alternatively, use `dict.get` to the same effect:

```
retry_after = response.headers.get('Retry_After')
```

Which will assign `retry_after` to the value of the key if it exists, or `None` otherwise.

Comment: This solved it Thanks! The problem was that i was getting the header with response.headers['retry_after'] rather than using .get('retry-after'). This Still works but throws an exception if header not found.